# Lua Tilemap collision handling

Tags: lua, collision

I am working on a platforming game and i am trying to get the collision detection to work, and failed miserably (the player does not detect anything). I wasn't able to find any help despite browsing every source that i can find. And so i am here to somehow get a helping hand.

```lua
function checkCollider(object1, object2, dir) 
    local w, h = _G.res.getSpriteBounds(object1.sprite) -- map
    local w2, h2 = _G.res.getSpriteBounds(object2.sprite) -- player
    
    local left1 = object1.x
    local left2 = object2.x
    local right1 = object1.x + w
    local right2 = object2.x + w2
    local top1 = object1.y
    local top2 = object2.y
    local bottom1 = object1.y + h
    local bottom2 = object2.y + h2
    
    if (dir == 0 and right1 < left2) then
    return false;
    end

    if (dir == 1 and left1 < right2) then
    return false;
    end

    if (dir == 2 and bottom1 < top2) then
    return false;
    end

    if (dir == 3 and top1 < bottom2) then
    return false;
    end

    return true; -- collided
    --[[
    if(dir == 1) then
        if (bottom1 < top2) then return nil end; vertical
        if (top1 > bottom2) then return nil end;    
    end
  
    if(dir == 0) then
        if (right1 < left2) then return nil end; horizontal
        if (left1 > right2) then return nil end;    
    end
    
    if(dir == 2) then
        if (right1 < left2) then return nil end; both vertical and horizontal
        if (left1 > right2) then return nil end;    
        if (bottom1 < top2) then return nil end;
        if (top1 > bottom2) then return nil end;
    end

    return true collided
    ]]
end
```

here's the code that uses the collider function.

```lua
  for k, v in _G.pairs(self.pixelNameTable) do
   local map = self:getChild(v.name)
    -- if the player has collided with a block that is not the void
    if (checkCollider(map, player, 0) or checkCollider(map, player, 1) 
    or checkCollider(map, player, 2) or checkCollider(map, player, 3)) and map.sprite ~= "" then
      player.tile = v.type -- collision detected, stop the player
    else
      player.tile = 0 -- collision not detected, free the player
    end
  end
```

I hope everything i said is clearly understandable.

Comment: Replace `left1 < right2` with `right2 < left1` and `top1 < bottom2` with `bottom2 < top1`

Comment: it still doesn't work even after the changes

Comment: Try `(checkCollider(map, player, 0) and checkCollider(map, player, 1) 
    or checkCollider(map, player, 2) and checkCollider(map, player, 3))`

Comment: still nothing yet.

Comment: And the remaining `or` should be replaced with `and` too!